# What is the most covered way of scripting Azure resources?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I know of ARM, the REST SDK and the CLI Powershell cmdlets.

What I want to know is; which of these has the most extensive support for scripting resources without having to touch the (indeed very slow) Azure Portal?

And I would also really like to know which one of these Microsoft usually ship first with regards to preview features?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic as "too broad" and "opinion-soliciting." As far as which ships first with preview features: such a question is speculation at best. Only the product teams know when they will ship features, and detailed roadmap content is typically not shared publicly. As for how you script: They each have their advantages, and you'll likely find yourself using a mix. Maybe combined with a DevOps automated pipeline. Really no way to tell what's right for your case.

Comment: This is in no way a "What is better X or Y" type of question. I am merely trying to see if it's possible to go with only one approach of deploying resources to Azure instead of having to combine multiple which only makes it more error prone.

Comment: I would also argue that it is not "opinion-soliciting". I know that there are people from Microsoft who answers questions here, and they or someone else might actually know if Microsoft has some guidelines as to which of these technologies have higher prioritization.

Comment: Of course I realize that teams at Microsoft might be able to freely pick of these, and if that is the case then that is the answer; there is no one most covered way of doing it. But let's find out first before dismissing, as that's what Q&A is for. Thanks

Comment: I disagree @DavidMakogon, while no one guarantees all features will be available in powershell or sli or sdk, they definitely are available in REST. that leaves you with arm templates. there are some features hidden under different API, not available to arm templates, thats true, still templates is your best bet

Comment: @jessehouwing With respect, if I may; I believe you are either misinterpreting how I mean "most covered" or simply biased to think I want to declare one technology the reign supreme. I don't.

I have one goal with this question; is it possible to double down on just one way of deploying resources to Azure, or is it not. That's it. I couldn't care less what people think of ARM vs CLI in terms of brevity.

I hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: Let's chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188827/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-54809088-what-is-the-most-covered-way-of-scri

Comment: If you know for a fact that each team can freely choose, then that is the answer, there is no most covered way. Do you know that for a fact? Then put that as an answer and I will accept :) I simply want to know if it's possible or not, and I guessed it wouldn't be. I can adjust our process accordingly, and let this go. Just as long as I actually *know* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each service in Azure is exposed using a REST API. Most of those APIs are publically supported. Some aren't.

It depends on the team that builds the elements that make up Azure and often their primary customer base. The Windows IaaS and AAD teams have been mostly PowerShell first. Machine learning and AI seem to favor azure-cli, which is built in Python, a very commonly used language in big data scenarios. The Azure Devops team has recently moved from the Visual Studio to the Azure brand (formerly Visual Studio Team Services, Visual Studio Online, Team Foundation Service preview). Their tools are mostly Node and Powershell based. Not everything in Azure is a "Resource", per se. So not all things are created or updated using Azure Resource Manager Templates (ARM).

So, unfortunately, there is no golden hammer when it comes to automating Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Azure REST Api is, obviously, the best way to go, but its the least convenient (there probably is a better word for this). I really like arm templates, they (basically) allow you to define REST api calls you want to do and allow to do some looping\parametrizing\etc. As arm templates are just a proxy for the rest api, they usually work really well.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :)

Arm templates are great, we use them for everything. Up until now that is, because they don't have support for Azure Search Index or Indexers.

Comment: well, there's nothing to be afraid of :) arm templates are ok, you just have to accept a few things about them :)

Comment: Clicked too fast, updated my response :) Not afraid of ARM, but REST ;)

Comment: All of the other methods described are calling REST underneath.  What this means is that there will ALWAYS be a way to do something in the REST API.  That can't be said for all the other methods.  Personally I use the CLI over PowerShell as it seems to have more functionality for Web Apps but I use PowerShell when working with AAD.